# Getting cookie data from get PHPSESSID in Java

Tags: java, php

Working on a Java app that sends POST data to a forum to post data. Works almost great. Seems if I don't have PHPSESSID cookie set I get a 403 but when I get cookies, its not one of those returned to me.

Any idea how I can get this cookie or is the only solution to disable?

Comment: Well it depends when the `session_start` is called in your PHP-software. You have to call that page first to retrieve the `PHPSESSID` cookie. If that's not what you want to ask, then please be more specific.